# Conditionally applying a pointwise operation

Tags: performance-tuning

I need to invert all entries in a matrix above a certain threshold. The implementation below is quite slow, what's the right way to speed it up?

```
d = 2048;
denom = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {d, d}];
Timing[
 cutoff = Max@Abs[denom]/10;
 sdiv = Map[If[Abs[#] > cutoff, 1/#, #] &, denom, {2}];
 ] (* {2.20966, Null} *)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just compile it? I get around a 4-7x speedup: `cf = Compile[{{mtx, _Real, 2}, {cutoff, _Real}},
  Map[If[Abs[#] > cutoff, 1/#, #] &, mtx, {2}], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]` Even without `CompilationTarget->"C"` I get around 1.5-2x speedup.

Answer (score 5):

```
d = 2048;
SeedRandom[1]
denom = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {d, d}];
First@RepeatedTiming[cutoff = Max@Abs[denom]/10;
  sdiv = Map[If[Abs[#] > cutoff, 1/#, #] &, denom, {2}];]
```

> ```
>  0.43
> ```

```
sdiv2 = Module[{mask = Unitize[Clip[denom, MinMax[denom]/10, {0, 0}]]},
     mask denom + (1 - mask )/denom ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.18
> ```

```
sdiv == sdiv2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: very clever! on my system the improvement is almost tenfold, 0.86 to 0.09